# Hive-Hbase Integration not working

Tags: hive, hbase

Hive Hbase integration not working for below version.
Hive - 1.2.1
Hbase - 1.2.3

We are able to create view for a Hbase table using HBaseStorageHandler,but not able to insert data to Hbase through that view.And below is the exception

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.setDurability(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Durability;)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.setDurability(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Durability;)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat$MyRecordWriter.write(HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat$MyRecordWriter.write(HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HivePassThroughRecordWriter.write(HivePassThroughRecordWriter.java:40)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:753)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:88)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:837)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.process(TableScanOperator.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.forward(MapOperator.java:162)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:163)
        ... 8 more

Comment: which version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache Hadoop 2.7.2

Comment: It says here, there is no method  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.setDurability. check your hbase-client jar whether it is 0.x